# Knockoutjs observableArray map single value

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have an observableArray with observable items and a button.
When I click on button start an ajax request and I need to update
the velues on the same rows of the button.

```
<div id="list" data-bind="foreach: Values">
    Name <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    Category <span data-bind="text: Category"></span>
    Index <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
    Price <span data-bind="text: Price"></span>
    <a id="button" href="#" data-bind="visible: Price > 0, click: $parent.read">read data</a><br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var TRow = function () {
        this.Id = ko.observable(0);
        this.Price = ko.observable(0);
        this.Name = ko.observable("");
        this.Category = ko.observable("");
    }

    var TList = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.Values = ko.observableArray([new TRow()]);

        this.read = function (data) {
            readdata(self, data);
        }
    }
    var List = new TList();
    ko.applyBindings(List, document.getElementById("list"));

    function readdata(vm, row) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/test/" + row.Id,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
               //How I can update Id, Price...???
               //It's possible to use "ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Value, {}, vm);" ???
               ...

            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: It depends on how is the `data` look like what you get back from the server! Please post some sample data what you get when calling your  service url`/api/test/`!

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Techsolo/dvvUP/1/) to your problem and refactored the `readdata` method to provide your expected functionality

```
function readdata(vm, row) {

  // Received sample data after calling url: "/api/test/" + row.Id(),
  var data = {Id:0,Name:"Hans",Category:1,Price: 2.2};

  for(var i = 0; i < vm.Values().length ; i++){
    if(row.Id() == data.Id){
        row.Name(data.Name);
        row.Category(data.Category);
        row.Price(data.Price);
        break;
    }
  }   
};
```

By the way: Do **not forget** the brakets in  **"/api/test/" + row.Id()** because `Id` is an `observable`, if you want the *current* value you have to run the `function`.

Comment: It's possible to use ko.mapping?

Comment: Tried it in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Techsolo/dvvUP/1/) with no success. if you find a solution to use `ko.mapping` here tell me.

Comment: @AlwaysHC of course that you can use the mapping plugin for this: http://jsfiddle.net/dvvUP/4/

Comment: @nemesv Thats right. My fault used it at the same line like in the question not in the `if` statement. Thanks ;)

Comment: No need to iterate over `vm.values()`; `row` is always going to be the appropriate entry, and if `ID()` doesn't match it means a problem on the server.